# More efficient use for a function that determines winner on user input

Tags: c++, function

So in my programming class lab, I was asked this question: *"Write a program that prompts users for the name and number of points of two basketball teams. Then, it uses a nested if to display the winner (if any) or a message stating a tie if both teams have the same number of points – One screen shot per scenario – use one function to determine the possible scenarios. "*

I got the answer, but I feel as though it could greatly be condensed and the only reason I put a function in is because it is required. I would like some help on how to make this function more efficient and useful for future code. Any tips would be much appreciated! (code below)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string bballTeam1;
string bballTeam2;
int scoreCheck(int, int);


int main() {

int winner;
int score1 = 0;
int score2 = 0;

cout << "Enter a basketball team name: ";
getline(cin, bballTeam1); //had to make sure to account for spaces
cout << endl;
cout << "Enter a basketball team name: ";
getline(cin, bballTeam2); //had to make sure to account for spaces
cout << endl;

cout << "How many points do the " << bballTeam1 << " have? ";
cin >> score1; //get points
cout << endl;
cout << "How many points do the " << bballTeam2 << " have? ";
cin >> score2; //get points
cout << endl;

winner = scoreCheck(score1, score2); // go to function

if(winner == 1) { //if statements to determine correct output
    cout << "The " << bballTeam1 << " are winning!" << endl;
}
else if(winner == 2) {
    cout << "The " << bballTeam2 << " are winning!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Looks like they are tied up!" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
int scoreCheck(int a, int b) { //a is score1, b is score2

int winner; //set value to int for output

if (a > b) {
    winner = 1; //1 is team 1
}
else if(a < b) {
    winner = 2; //2 is team 2
}
else if(a == b) {
    winner = 0; //0 is tie
}

return winner; //returns value of winner
}
```

Comment: Seems crazy to make a function that compares scores using an `if` statement, then have to use another `if` statement to decode the results of it

Comment: Off topic: instead of returning an `int` with magic number values, consider something like `enum result { TEAM1, TEAM2, TIE };`. Not so useful for a little program like this, but the compiler can perform additional checks to make sure no one is doing anything silly and it's never too early to get into good habits.

Comment: A good place to use a function here is for input validation to ensure the user inputs good scores. Currently the program can be trashed by the user typing in something like "fubar" instead of a number or nonsensical values like negative numbers or pi to a hundred decimal points.

Comment: Come to think of it, this question would be better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because this is working code that OP wishes to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sitting down to write a function, one of the first things to think about is the best interface for the function: what values it will take, and what will it return.

Some factors to consider here are the purpose of the function, the available inputs, and how the function will be used.

In your case you have created a function which takes two integers as input, performs some very simple logic on them, and returns another integer which is coded with special values to represent the outcome. While this is valid and works, it is awkward in the use case you are putting it to: immediately after calling the function you need to use very similar logic to act on the result.

I would be more inclined to make the function return a string which represents the outcome of the score check, like this:

```
string scoreCheck(int score1, string team1,  int score2, string team2) {

    string result;

    if (score1 > score2) {
        result = "The "+team1+" are winning!";
    }
    else if(score1 < score2) {
        result = "The "+team2+" are winning!";
    }
    else {
        result = "Looks like they are tied up!";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then, you could simplify your main function, replacing all the if/then branches with this:

```
cout << scoreCheck(score1, bballTeam1, score2, bballTeam2) << endl;
```

It all boils down to how the function will be used - in this case what we want from the function is a string representing the result of the game which we can directly output. The function is not being used in any other contexts in the program, so we should make it fit this use case as well as possible.

Also note that I changed the last part of the nested if to a plain 'else' - there was no need to check that score1 == score2 since we had already eliminated the other cases.